# Options page for widget

Tags: widgets, options

I started developing a plugin which only required a few options. But over time the number of settings grew, and I want to move most of them to a separate page. I've seen quite a few tutorials about options pages and about widgets, but I couldn't find one that explained how to create an options page for a particular widget.

How can this be achieved ? I intend to keep only a couple of settings that would affect individual instances, and the rest would be global, and on the options page.

Comment: Hate to link my own plugin, but check out the code in my disqus recent comments widget plugin, I have both an options page using the settings api and individual options for each widget instance: http://wordpress.org/plugins/disqus-recent-comments-widget/

Comment: @AndrewBartel I was actually going to ask for a simple example plugin, yours looks just like what I needed :D

Answer (score 0):

Your widget is part of a plugin (per the first sentence of the question), so what you are really talking about is making a plugin administration page, which you would do with [`add_menu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page), [`add_submenu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page), or [one of the more specialize menu page functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus#Function_Reference). That is the nutshell version of the answer.

There are a lot of questions and answers here about doing that and there are examples in the Codex. Once you get started, if you have trouble, [edit] the question with your code and with an explanation of the specific problems you are having, ping me (@s_ha_dum in a comment) and I will edit the answer. Otherwise, it is really a very broad question.